# How to test if a model has a custom macro method that is called during execution in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my model, I run the method `redefine_associations!` during execution:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class MyModule < AnotherModule
  redefine_associations!
end

class AnotherModule < ApplicationRecord
  def self.redefine_associations!
    belongs_to :user
  end

  redefine_associations!
end
```

How can I test that my model has `redefine_associations!`.

I tried the following which did not work:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
RSpec.MyModule VisitDate do
  it { expect(subject).to have_received(:redefine_associations!) }
  it { should respond_to(:redefine_associations!) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a macro method, the easiest way to test this would be:

```
  let(:class_file_array) do
    File.readlines(Rails.root.join('app/models/my_module.rb'))
  end

  it 'calls redefine_associations!' do
    expect(class_file_array.include?("  redefine_associations!\n")).to be true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to check if that `redefine_associations` method defined for that model. Then you can do it like this:

`it { expect(subject.methods.includes?(:redefine_associations!)).to eql(true) }`

Comment: I wanted to check if the method was called instead of defined.

Comment: If the method weren't defined, the class eval would raise an exception at runtime. But also, test your expectation, I'm pretty sure that spec will fail.